# ubuntu 18.042LTS wont reboot without instillation software

Tags: uefi

Ubuntu boots fine, the only problem I have is when I shut my pc down.
It won't reboot without the installation media. 
This started happening when I was running Fedora & tried to activate su.
I notice grub wasn't recognising my boot directory.
After I couldn't get anything right with Fedora I tried ubuntu.
I have been trying to fix this problem with ubuntu for about a week now

I have tried a boot repair, the details are here http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/6CR7DDWftK/
I tried to contact intel but they said they don't offer support for these drivers anymore but pointed me to this web page https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/23393/BIOS-Update-BEH6110H-86A-?product=60652
I see intel have stopped the BEH6110H.86A.0038 firmware update as it may cause the system to no longer boot
My motherboard is a BEH6110H.86A.0028
I am unable to post demsg as it is too long.
I did try to flush my bios by by making a bottable usb drive with unebootin.
I think the problem might be with the bios software.
any assistance will be appreciated.

Comment: Make sure the UEFI settings are correct for UEFI mode and then select "Ubuntu" in the boot order.

Comment: Pc freezes when I try to change any settings in EFI (press F10 & select y)

Comment: So you may have an hardware problem. Try reseting the motherboard.

Answer (score 0):

I reset my cmos & that fixed my bios problem.
The plain Ubuntu boots from legacy which my pc doesn't like.
I then booted from UEFI Ubuntu which worked.
Setting efi as boot loader caused my pc to reboot to the Grub screen.
[code] I then set /boot  as the bootloader which solved the problem[/code]

Thanks Grabriella